# Why should I use the const keyword when creating an object from a class with a constant constructor?

Tags: dart

Lets say I have the following:

```dart
var example = SizedBox();
```

dart then recommends that I add `const` before `SizedBox`:

```dart
var example = const SizedBox();
```

I understand what the `const` keyword does, but what I don't understand is why I have to write it in the example above, since the constructor of `SizedBox` is const. Wouldn't all instances of `SizedBox` be constant without writing it each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Wouldn't all instances of SizedBox be constant each time without writing it`

It seems like that but it is not the case, it does a create a new instance if you don't use `const` explicitly. The reason is that the linter recommends you to add it is to improve memory allocation i.e. allocate lesser memory because the nature of `SizedBox` is such that it doesn't have to change because it is indeed a sized box which once initialized doesn't have to change

You can read some more interesting facts on this [post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-flutter-const-keyword-demystified-c8d2a2609a80)

So TLDR:

Why? To save memory and improve hot reload performance and prevent re-rendering
How? Read the above post